# Adding additional columns to a JIRA report

Tags: report, jira

I am learning JIRA. Currently I am learning about various reports that can be generated using JIRA. What should I do if I want to have additional column in a report generated using JIRA? For example, in the Single Level Group By report, the following info are given: issue no, issue description, status of the issue. Now, I want to add additional information, say, "issue created at" which gives the date the issue is created. How to do the above?

Answer (score 0):

JIRA is somehow limited in its onboard abilities to create reports. You have the default reports, that come with JIRA and you can only customize them to the extend you've already seen. You could a) export a filtered list to an external application to evaluate it there, b) create a custom addon yourself or c) install a thirdparty addon (probably paid) from Atlassian's marketplace.